# How to know when a form is done loading or is loading in MS Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a way to know when a form is finished loading, or to know that it is loading?

One of the reasons I want to know this, is I have a save routine within a drop down box [Updated] event.  This event gets called when the form is loading, and I want to only call it when someone manually changes the selection, not when the form changes it.

Comment: *this event gets called when the form is loading* - so you have code that does that? Please [edit] your question with a [mcve] to show us what's going on *with code*. If you have code that handles the form loading, then you already know when the form is loading..

Comment: Could you use the Lost Focus event instead of the After Update Event?  Or maybe setting a boolean to False on the form's On Open event then set it to True at the end of the control's After Update event and using that as the condition to run the routine?

Comment: Something like that might work Jeffrey.  I was using a flag on Open and trying to find the correct event to set it back to false... using the controls Update event might work best.

Comment: That combo boxes update event wouldn't normally get called during form load, so there must be some code somewhere calling it.  I suggest, as others have that you post up the OnLoad and OnOpen code for the form.